# Arrange rows in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, rows

How to arrange rows manually in T-SQL?

I have a table result in order like this:

- Unknown
- Charlie
- Dave
- Lisa
- Mary

but the expected result is supposed to be:

- Charlie
- Dave
- Lisa
- Mary
- Unknown

*edited:*

My whole query is:

```
select (case when s.StudentID is null then 'Unknown' else s.StudentName end) as StudentName from Period pd full join Course c on pd.TimeID = c.TimeID full join Student s on c.StudentID = s.StudentID
group by s.StudentName, s.StudentID
order by case s.StudentName
            when 'Charlie' then 1
            when 'Dave' then 2
            when 'Lisa' then 3
            when 'Mary' then 4
            when 'Unknown' then 5 
            end
```

but it didn't work. I think the problem root is because Unknown is from NULL value, as I wrote in that query that when StudentID is null then change "NULL" to "Unknown". Is this affecting the "stubborn" order of the result? By the way I also have tried `order by s.StudentName asc` but also didn't work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see your rows must be ordered alphabetically, so just add in the end of the query: `ORDER BY p.StudentName`.
If this not help, please add whole query, so we can find out the problem.

So when I see query I can explain. You try to sort by column p.StudentName. This column contains NULL. Try to sort by StudentName without p in front. This is alias of the expression which contains Unknown.

Comment: I've tried that one, but also didn't change anything. I've edited my question. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it. Where is column 'a' from? I don't see there is column a there.

Comment: I use tablet an did not see whole text. Try only StudentName to sort by the result of the expression. When you sort by p.StudentName you sort by the column that contains NULL. So when you sort by StudentName only you sort by result of the expression which contain Unknown.

Comment: Sorry not p., but s. you change alias

Comment: Ah! Yes it works! Just knew that p.StudentName and StudentName only have 2 different meaning. So, just want to ensure my understanding, s.StudentName means the engine sorts based on the source database, right?

Comment: Yes, when you order you can use column from DB or alias from select. You try to use column (which contains NULL). You have to use alias which corresponds to the expression result and contains Unknown, instead of NULl.

Comment: Ok, it's very clear for me now. Thanks for your help and explanation. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following...

```
SELECT  os.StudentName
FROM    ( SELECT    CASE WHEN s.StudentID IS NULL THEN 'Unknown'
                         ELSE s.StudentName
                    END AS StudentName
          FROM      Period pd
                    FULL JOIN Course c ON pd.TimeID = c.TimeID
                    FULL JOIN Student s ON c.StudentID = s.StudentID
          GROUP BY  s.StudentName ,
                    s.StudentID
        ) AS os
ORDER BY os.StudentName
```

Edit: based on comment...

When I use this, it works fine...notice the `Order By` has no identifier

```
declare  @tblStudent TABLE (StudentID int, StudentName varchar(30));

insert into @tblStudent values (null, '');
insert into @tblStudent values (1, 'Charlie');
insert into @tblStudent values (2, 'Dave');
insert into @tblStudent values (3, 'Lisa');
insert into @tblStudent values (4, 'Mary');

SELECT  CASE WHEN s.StudentID IS NULL THEN 'Unknown'
             ELSE s.StudentName
        END AS StudentName
FROM    @tblStudent s
GROUP BY s.StudentName ,
        s.StudentID
ORDER BY StudentName
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the instruction doesn't allow me to use subquery. Really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

just put the following clause in you SQL statement: 
`order by p.StudentName` 
Sql server will order the column alphabetically.

Comment: I tried that one but also didn't change anything. My question has been edited so maybe you can help me with my problem. Thanks.